# How to make elements responsive within a div width rather than the window width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website editor. I am using Bootstrap 5.  I have toggle buttons that can be changed from mobile to desktop view. However when I adjust the width of this div the element won't responsively change, I found out that is because they will only responsively change to the width of actual window size.

Question is can I make a div behave like a window?  Are there other alternatives that I can add elements into beside a div as a container?

[image: navbar unresponsive to size of div]

Comment: Please post some HTML and CSS that reproduces your issue so we can best help with your challenge. FWIW many browsers already have that build in so you can see your page either way.

Comment: give us some code please

Comment: flexbox and grid might be what you are looking for